# How to repeat an if or switch statement if something out of option is entered?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

This will mostly get duplicated but I sincerely don't know how to search this question since it is too long and complicated. Sorry in advance!

Back to the problem, let's say I take an input from the user with the Scanner class. Imagine that Scanner is imported and everything is set.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
String input = scan.nextLine();
switch( input) {
    case "attack":
       System.out.println( "You attacked the enemy!");
       break;

    case "defend":
       System.out.println( "You blocked the enemy!");
       break;

    default:
       System.out.println( "This is not an option!");
       // somehow repeat the process until one of the case options are 
       // entered.
}
```

How do I repeat this process of asking for an input and checking for a case until a case is executed?

I could put this inside a while loop and when a case option is entered I could exit out of the while loop, but that just seems too much code when I have plenty of switch/if statements that both require a solid input in order to process the rest of the code.
Is there a way to do this more efficiently in Java?

Comment: I am not clear with what you are asking, would you like a different method of input? or a more efficient way to do a switch statement?

Comment: What I am asking is written as a comment inside the switch statement. I'm looking for a way to repeat the process if the user enters something like "ashfh" as the input. So the code should ask for an input until "attack" or "defend" is entered.

Comment: A while loop with your default clause setting the while condition to false is a pretty standard way to deal with this and about 3 lines of extra code in the whole thing

Comment: You could create a `Map<String, String>` and then check if the `Map` has the `key` instead of `switch`.

Comment: as @pvg said, just put the code in a while loop and do nothing in the default clause, this is the most clean way to do what you would like

Comment: @ElliottFrisch still requires some control structure to keep repeating the check until valid input.

Comment: @pvg True. But you could also extract it into a reusable method, assuming you need to gather multiple types of input. OP's question isn't quite clear enough for an answer, hence the comment.

Comment: Alright then, I was in doubt because while loops was the first thing that came to my mind, and usually that is the least efficient way when we talk about programming. But now that you guys are suggesting the same, I'm guessing I'll go for it. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am sorry for the complicated question, I can't express myself good enough since English isn't my native language neither the programming language :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
loop:
while (true) {
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    switch (input) {
        case "attack":
            System.out.println("You attacked the enemy!");
            break loop;

        case "defend":
            System.out.println("You blocked the enemy!");
            break loop;

        default:
            System.out.println("This is not an option!");
            break;
    }
}
```

`while (true)` makes an infinite loop as you may know. In the switch statement, if the input is attack or defend, we break out of the loop. If it is neither of those, we only break out of the switch statement.

The while loop is marked with the `loop:` label. This is so that we can tell it to `break loop;` to break out of the loop. On the other hand `break` only breaks out of the switch statement.

Comment: That was my way of fixing it as well, only that I'm not using the break loop; I just made a boolean run and then I set run to false in cases. But marking the loop like that was something I didn't know, TIL.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option would be to create a `Map<String, String>` with valid options and pass it to a method with an infinite loop, if the user provides a valid option return it (possibly after performing some action); otherwise display the invalid option message and loop again. Like,

```
public static String getCommand(Scanner scan, Map<String, String> options) {
    while (true) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        if (options.containsKey(input)) {
            System.out.println(options.get(input));
            return input;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s is not an option!%n", input);
        }
    }
}
```

The above could then be called like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("attack", "You attacked the enemy!");
options.put("defend", "You blocked the enemy!");
String cmd = getCommand(scan, options);
```

After which `cmd` would be one of `attack` or `defend`. Note that this way you can add as many `options` (or type of `options`) as you need, and reuse `getCommand`.

Comment: Whoa nice! This look more promising.

Answer (score 0):

So if you enter defend or attack, it will not ask again, otherwise repeat the process. Try this:

```
    do{
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    switch( input) {
        case "attack":
           System.out.println( "You attacked the enemy!");
           break;

        case "defend":
           System.out.println( "You blocked the enemy!");
           break;

        default:
           System.out.println( "This is not an option!");
           // somehow repeat the process until one of the case options are 
           // entered.
    }
}while(!"attack".equalsIgnoreCase(input) || !"defend".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
```

Comment: This answer also works but gets too long if inside the while() part if I have 10 cases or so. I'm going to stick with the way of creating a while loop instead.

Comment: yes you are right, for that case while would be best.